# How can i remove the final characters in a string (python)

Tags: python, string

How can I remove the final characters from a string in python until I reach a certain amount of characters?

How can I turn: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz => abcdefghijklmnopqr; using python?

Comment: "reach a certain number of characters"? Is a certain length left (`string[:length]`) or deleted (`string[:-length]`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try string slicing.

You can use negative indexing:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:-8]
```

or positive:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:18]
```

Pick your poison

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the string as an array of symbols

```
c_1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
l = 18
c_2 = c_2[:l]
```